# data frame cannot be subsetted by using cbind() with selector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a data frame by using the `cbind()` function and `$` selecting the colum names:

```
stormData <- read.csv("/Users/b.w.h/Documents/R/Coursera/Reproducible Research /Project 2/repdata-data-StormData.csv");
stormDataSubset <- as.data.frame(c(stormData$STATE, stormData$EVTYPE, stormData$FATALITIES, stormData$INJURIES));
head(stormDataSubset);
```

But it only returns the index column and the state column:

[image]

Why isn't this subsetting method working? And what should I do to properly subset it? Thanks!

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use **dplyr** and then use the **select()** function.

Comment: @kashj why not just `data[c("var1", "var2", "var3")]`? If this issue is just to select variables, it's no need to use an external package.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, you're right actually. I am wondering how it just didn't cross my mind. Anyways, I hope Kaihua Hou won't mind learning something extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the columns are added one below the another, making it only one column. You can use

```
stormDataSubset <- cbind.data.frame(stormData$STATE, stormData$EVTYPE, stormData$FATALITIES, stormData$INJURIES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **dplyr**

```
stormDataSubset <- stormData %>% select(STATE,EVTYPE,FATALITIES,INJURIES)
```

If all these columns are continuous and in sequence, then it's better to use

```
stormDataSubset <- stormData %>% select(STATE:INJURIES)
```

And there you go. It's done.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `cbind`

```
stormDataSubset <- as.data.frame(cbind(stormData$STATE, stormData$EVTYPE, stormData$FATALITIES, stormData$INJURIES))
```

Comment: It's dangerous to `cbind()` multiple vectors and then `as.data.frame()`. If these vectors have multiple classes, e.g. `numeric` and `character`, `cbind()` will change them all to characters. So after `as.data.frame()`, you will get a data with overall character columns.

Comment: A better alternative is `cbind.data.frame()`, which does not change data types.